# Backbone populate Model inside of a Collection

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

So here is my scenario:

I have a Backbone Collection full of Models. For performance reasons, however, these are not "full" Models. My "full" Models are quite large (imagine each "full" Model has a sub-collection of equally large objects), so when I fetch the Collection from the server I return an array of "partial" Models whose properties are a subset of the "full" model (for example I return only the length of the sub-collection instead of the full sub-collection), just enough to display the Models in a list view to the user.

Now when the user selects an item from the list, I fetch the "full" Model from the server and show a details view of that Model. The problem I have is that now I have two versions of the same Model, one "partial" in the Collection and one "full", and manually having to keep them in sync isn't the right way to do things.

What I'm wondering is if there is an existing pattern (in Backbone or Marionette) for "populating" a "partial" Model into a "full" Model while keeping all of the same references, and for "depopulating" the same Model from a "full" Model into a "partial" Model when we no longer need all of the extra data (i.e. the user navigates to another item in the list).

I have full control over both the front-end and the back-end of my application, and can make changes accordingly if a pattern requires I change what the server returns.

Comment: Assuming the "partial" model is a subset of the "full" model, what prevents you from filling models that live in the collection so you have one model that starts as "basic" and extends to "extended" upon select?

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, I'm just wondering if there is a nice pattern I can use or if I have to roll my own. Basically I want to know if someone has already done something like this and has any pointers they'd be willing to share. My general idea at the moment is to have a populated flag on the Model and populate and depopulate functions.

Comment: Can't you just call [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) on individual models living in the collection to load the full set of properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are representing a single domain object (albeit in two different forms), so you should use a single `Model` instance to cover both cases.

One fairly clean pattern:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // ... existing code...

  inflate: function() {
    return $.ajax({
      // parameters to fetch the full version
    }).then(function(data) {
      // process the response - something like this:
      this.set({
        a: data.a,
        b: data.b
      }, { silent: true })

      this.trigger('inflate')
    })
  },

  deflate: function() {
    this.unset('a', { silent: true });
    this.unset('b', { silent: true });

    // any other cleanup to prevent leaking the large attributes

    this.trigger('deflate')
  }
})
```

This pattern uses the custom `inflate` and `deflate` events in preference to firing `change`, because it's semantically more accurate.

You could, of course, DRY up the code by maintaining an array of attribute names that should be in/deflated.

Comment: This is essentially what I was planning on doing, but I like how you trigger custom `inflate` and `deflate` events. Now I just have to figure out how to load both the collection of objects and a single object in parallel (when a user deep links to a single item) then make sure all of the references point to the same `Model`. Not hard, per se, just awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Just like your collection has a URL to the "partial" models, your models should have a URL to the full versions:

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book,
    url: "/books"
});

var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function () {
        return "/books/" + this.get("id");
    }
});
```

When you click your item view use that same model, call a fetch(), and pass it into the detail view.

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "li",

    events: {
        "click .details": "openBook"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        // ...
    },

    openBook: function () {
        this.model.fetch();
        var bookDetailView = new BookDetailView({ model: this.model });
        // Or create the view after successful fetch...
    }

    // ...

});

var BookDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

You won't have two versions of the same model. The model in the collection view will now have all the attributes, but it will only display what is in the template.

As far as "depopulating" it doesn't seem necessary. If the item is clicked again you could even check if the "full" model data is available and lose the extra fetch. If you really want to drop the data, then go ahead and create a method on the model to unset the attributes.